# DEBUG - ConfigurationUtils.locate(): base is null

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons

I am using apache common PropertiesConfiguration to load properties file and currently I am using something like this

```
public class PropertiesConfig {
private Configuration config;
private Logs logger = new Logs();

public PropertiesConfig(){
    try {
        config = new PropertiesConfiguration(Constant.PROP_FILE_PATH+Constant.PROP_FILE_NAME);
    } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    logger.info("Properties File Loaded : "+Constant.PROP_FILE_PATH+Constant.PROP_FILE_NAME);
    }
 public String[] getPropertiesByArray(String key){
    return config.getStringArray(key);
}
}
```

And this is how I load it in my controller class

```
 public void loadConfig(){
    this.dir = config.getPropertiesByArray(Constant.PROP_DIR_CONFIG);
    logger.info("Loading Dir path list from propeties config");
    for(String d : dir){
        logger.info("Dir Set: "+d);
}
```

But in my console I am having this debug msg

```
2013-04-04 14:14:18,657
DEBUG - ConfigurationUtils.locate(): base is null, name is conf/configuration.properties

2013-04-04 14:14:18,672
DEBUG - Loading configuration from the path conf\configuration.properties

2013-04-04 14:14:18,688
INFO  - Properties File Loaded : conf/configuration.properties
```

It is loading my properties file but I am not sure how to get rid of that debug msg

Answer (score 2):

The first two messages are just debug messages. Your logger must be configured to show them.

You have to configure your logger to filter `org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils` messages as INFO (or above).